# Fish: Iterate over a string

Tags: shell, fish

How would you iterate over a string in the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/)?

Unfortunately iterating over a string isn't as straight forward as iterating over a list:

```
↪ for c in a b c
      echo $c
  end
a
b
c

↪ for c in abc
      echo $c
  end
abc
```

Comment: That doesn't work in fish because there isn't any explicit syntax for constructing a list or tuple like there is with Python's `[...]` and `(...)` constructs. You need to explicitly explode the string into a list of chars as Dennis' answer explains.

Answer (score 10):

The `for` loop in fish operates on a list.

```
for VARNAME in [VALUES...]; COMMANDS...; end
```

The builtin `string` command (since v2.3.0) can be used to split a string into a list of characters.

```
↪ string split '' abc
a
b
c
```

The output is a list, so array operations will work.

```
↪ for c in (string split '' abc)
      echo $c
  end
a
b
c
```

A more complex example iterating over the string with an index.

```
↪ set --local chars (string split '' abc)
  for i in (seq (count $chars))
      echo $i: $chars[$i]
  end
1: a
2: b
3: c
```